# How to Choose a Port Number?

Tags: network-programming, zeromq

I'm writing a program which uses ZeroMQ to communicate with other running programs on the same machine. I want to choose a port number at run time to avoid the possibility of collisions. Here is an example of a piece of code I wrote to accomplish this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Tw

use strict;
use warnings;

my %in_use;
{
    local $ENV{PATH} = '/bin:/usr/bin';

    %in_use = map { $_ => 1 } split /\n/, qx(
        netstat -aunt          |\
        awk '{print \$4}'      |\
        grep :                 |\
        awk -F: '{print \$NF}'
    );
}

my ($port) = grep { not $in_use{$_} } 50_000 .. 59_999;

print "$port is available\n";
```

The procedure is:

1. invoke netstat -aunt
2. parse the result
3. choose the first port on a fixed range which doesn't appear on netstat list.

Is there a system utility better suited to accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)    
port_selected = socket.bind_to_random_port('tcp://*', min_port=6001, max_port=6004, max_tries=100)
```

Comment: Sweet! However, it looks like the bind_to_random_port(...) method only exists for the Python driver. While looking that up, I discovered that  ZMQ v3 supports a wildcard port number which you can follow up with getsockopt( ZMQ_LAST_ENDPOINT ).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, from your code it looks like you are trying to choose a port between 70000 and 79999. You do know that port numbers only go up to 65535, right? :-)

You can certainly do it this way, even though there are a couple of problems with the approach. The first problem is that `netstat` output differs between different operating systems so it's hard to do it portably. The second problem is that you still need to wrap the code in a loop which tries again to find a new port number in case it was not possible to bind to the chosen port number, because there's a race condition between ascertaining that the port is free and actually binding to it.

If the library you are using allows you to specify the port number as 0 and allows you to call `getsockname()` on the socket after it is bound, then you should just do that. Using 0 makes the system choose any free port number, and with `getsockname()` you can find out which port it chose.

Failing that, it would probably actually be more efficient to not bother calling `netstat` and just try to find to different port numbers in a loop. If you succeed, break from the loop. If you fail, increment the port number by 1, go back, and try again.

Comment: Oh, that's a little dumb -- corrected the invalid port range. 
No, ZMQ doesn't accept a port number of zero. 
Yes, it's that race condition that's got me hesitating.